# Chart.js Custom Legend Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I have a custom legend made for some of my charts. With this I am hoping to add a option similar to:

```
        legend:{
            labels: {
                usePointStyle: true,
            },
```

This would allow my legend to have multiple plots using the same color but having different plot styling.
My default legend is set to `display:false`.

Here is how my legend is generated:

```
totalLegendContainer.innerHTML = totalChart.generateLegend();
var legendItems = totalLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i += 1) {
  legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback, false);
}
```

The styling currently comes from `CSS`

```
#fakeLegendID{
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #666;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 280px;
    width: 140px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

How would I add the ability to have my legend show how the line is styled?